# uniform_real_distribution<float> is returning 1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, c++20, uniform-distribution

I've observed that a sample generated from a `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>` can be equal to `1` (compiled using Visual Studio 2022).

This is in contrast to the description in standard stating that it should be a uniform draw from `[0, 1)`; hence `1` should be excluded.

Is this cause I'm using `float` instead of `double`? Or is this a bug in the Visual Studio 2022 implementation?

And what can I do now? It is important for me that the draw is from `[0, 1)` and not from `[0, 1]`. My current solution is to replace the draw `u` by `u - std::floor(u)`.

Comment: @PeterO. Thank you for the link; it is really interesting. However, I've now tested it with `double` instead of `float` and it still happens that the outcome can be `1`.

Comment: would be interesting to see the code that's giving you that!  as a quick work around I think I'd just use rejection sampling, CPU cost should be negligible as rejections should be very rare